# Summation series question divergent inequality

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, summation, integral-inequality

where n is > 0 and an integer
k(n) = ln(n)
 $$h(n) =\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$$

prove h(n) > k(n)
ive tried and considered that h(n) is a divergent series so when n approaches infinity, im not sure how to prove that h(n) is bigger becuase the series sum doesn't converge to a value. I think k(n) also approaches infinity.

Comment: Compare $h(n)$ with the lower Riemann sum corresponding to $\int_{1}^{n}\frac{dt}{t}=\ln(n)$ and the partition at the integers.

Comment: is it becuase the area is bigger than the sum when using rectangles?

Comment: Yes, that's the intuition. Strictly speaking the area is defines as that integral. The reason why the integral is larger than the lower Riemann sum is because the integral is equal to the supremum of all such sums, and in particular the supremum is larger than any one of the sums.

Comment: i realised that but im not sure how to formally proove this?

Comment: @nihaal Use induction. The difference is always positive so you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on arugula's comments, we can write $$ \ln(n)=\int_1^n\frac{dt}{t} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \int_{k}^{k+1} \frac{dt}{t} \le \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}\int_{k}^{k+1}dt = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k} = h(n)-\frac{1}{n} < h(n)$$ where we used the fact that $\frac{1}{k}\ge \frac{1}{t}$ for $t\in [k,k+1].$

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider, $x∈[1,\infty)$, and $\varphi:x\rightarrow \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor}$.

$\displaystyle\int_1^{n+1}\varphi(x)dx=\sum_{k=1}^n\int_k^{k+1}f(x)dx=\sum_{k=1}^nk$

Let us consider, $\psi:x\rightarrow\frac{1}{x}$.

$\lfloor x\rfloor≤x$, hence $\frac{1}{x}≤\frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor}$, which means $\psi(x)\leq \varphi(x)$.

$\displaystyle\int_1^{n+1}\psi(x)dx=\int_1^{n+1}\frac{1}{x}dx=\ln(n+1)−\ln1=\ln(n+1)$

Let us consider, $f:x↦\begin{cases}1 & if & x\leq 2 \\ \frac{1}{x-1} & if & x>2\end{cases}$.

$x−1\leq\lfloor x \rfloor$, hence $\frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor}\leq\frac{1}{x−1}$, which means $\varphi(x)\leq f(x)$ for $x>2$; for $x\in[1,2],\varphi(x)=f(x)=1$.

$\displaystyle\int_1^{n+1}f(x)dx=1+\ln n$

Now since, $\psi(x)≤\varphi(x)≤f(x)$,

Hence,
$\ln(n+1)\leq 1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}≤1+\ln n$